# "Sherlock and queries" challenge

Tags: java, optimization, programming-challenge

I'm writing some Java code for some pretty large datasets, in a puzzle I'm trying to solve.  The output is correct, but the program doesn't run within the time limit for all the test cases.  I've tried a number of optimizations, but can't think about how to improve it.  I'd appreciate your suggestions.

The puzzle is [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-queries).

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
int N = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
int M = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
long[] A = new long[N];
int[] B = new int[M];
long[] C = new long[M];    
tok = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) A[i] = Long.parseLong(tok.nextToken());
tok = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) B[i] = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
tok = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) C[i] = Long.parseLong(tok.nextToken());
br.close();

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = B[i] - 1; j < N; j += B[i]) {
        A[j] = (A[j] * C[i]) % 1000000007;
    }
}
for (long l : A) System.out.print(l + " ");
```

Comment: [Can you please provide the context to the question here?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1993/41243) [Links are unreliable](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2015/41243).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the beefs I have with online judging systems like this..... it is not testing the algorithm, or anything like that. Instead, consider doing the very last line like:

```
// the longest value will be 11 chars long because % 1000000007 + " "
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(N * 11);
for (long l : A) {
    sb.append(l).append(" ");
}
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

A single `println` is almost always `N` times faster than `N` `println`s.

If that does not make it work in time, then consider reading the entire System.in in to a buffer, and parsing it from the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner` is very ergonomic for parsing inputs, you can simplify your code quite a bit, instead of `StringTokenizer` (of which you created many):

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        int M = scanner.nextInt();
        long[] A = new long[N];
        int[] B = new int[M];
        int[] C = new int[M];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) A[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) B[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) C[i] = scanner.nextInt();

        // ...
    }
}
```

All the input values fit within an `int`, so I changed the type of `C` to `int[]`, and use `.nextInt` for all inputs. I left the type of `A` as `long[]` to let the `A[i] * C[i]` calculation step exceed the `int` limit (before the modulo).

---

Another thing, `BufferedReader` closes the underlying stream, in this case `System.in` ([see the implementation on grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.close%28%29)). I think it's not a good practice to close a stream you didn't open, normally it should be the caller's responsibility.

---

How about giving the \$10^9 + 7\$ constant a name:

```
private static final int MODULO = (int) 1e9 + 7;
```

---

Unfortunately none of this will get you pass all tests. I have a feeling that the fastest solution is more a matter of math and logic than code review material.

---

Btw, next time it's good if you include the full code. That way we can test run our suggestions easier on the hosting website, otherwise we have to guess that the implementation must be in the `main` method of a class named `Solution`.

Comment: You're right, I had a peek at the "Editorial" tab on the problem page, which says that OP's algorithm will time out, and suggests a faster way.

Comment: @mjolka the description of "Editorial" was difficult to understand, but that is what I ended up going by.  Problem solved.